# Как сделать так, чтобы боковое меню было на всю высоту страницы?

Tags: html, css

Сейчас боковое меню на всю высоту, но если начать прокручивать сайт вниз, то оно сразу заканчивается. Как сделать так, чтобы оно было во всю высоту сайта?

```css
aside{
    float: left;
    background: #955815;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 2.5%;
    border-right: 5px solid #272727;
}
```

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: Для полноты ответа нужно показать некий "полный" тестовый пример, вместе с `html`... Поскольку интересно знать информацию про родителей этого "бокового меню".